# How do i group a list of dynamic objects using linq given that the property names are dynamic?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to group the results from a dynamic object list. 
I tried the following code

```
    var results = ((IEnumerable)data).Cast<dynamic>().Where(x => x.dynamicProperyname));
```

The property name itself is also dynamic and hence i cannot use it in my query as shown above. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: what is the data *actually*? does it support an indexer API?

Comment: You can use reflection to get the type, then get the property, and then get the value. Why though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick -

```
var propertyName = "dynamicProperyname";
var results = ((IEnumerable)data).Cast<dynamic>()
              .Where(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(x, null) ?? false);
```

Above code use reflection to get value of property.